# How to determine if the device is mobile when rotated horizontally on React?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive

I am trying to determine the device if it is mobile (ex: iPhone 12 Pro: 390x844) when rotated horizontally. Because the height of this device (844) is larger than the width of the tablet (768).

Comment: What do you define as mobile? Do you mean mobile or do you mean some aspect ratio or…?

Comment: Thank for your question! I am talking about some aspect ratios (similar to breakpoint)

Comment: Have you investigated media queries aspect-ratio and/or orientation?

Comment: IMO, you should check what the device is and then populate styles. That's what my team did before. Check out this repo: https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js/

Comment: @hungdoansy how do you reliably check for a device (as opposed to checking eg viewport dimensions)?

Comment: @AHaworth By the user agent (UA)

Comment: @hungdoansy  User agents can not always be relied on, and there are many devices out there.

Comment: It's up to you bro. I have been using the lib for a few years and haven't got any problems. If you have trust issues using it, manually check yourself :D